# AWS automatic failover over different region

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is it possible to automate a failover plan over different regions in AWS, for example US-east and California or Singapore?

Comment: Could you please clarify? Which product(s) are you working with? EC2? Give us a general overview of your solution.

Comment: we have 2 sets of ec2 one primary and other secondary:

Comment: primary consists of 2 EC2's with both Apache tomcat and 1 of them has mysql db too.

Comment: Secondary will consists of eith one server with 2 Tomcat application and db. Replication is done from primary to secondary.

Answer (score -1):

AWS doesn't have many multi-region services, and can't fail EC2 instances to different regions with standard offerings. At the 2012 AWS re:Invent conference they said they prefer multi-AZ within a single region because latency between AZs is very low, and different AZs are still several miles apart, isolating them fairly well from each other.

They do recommend using separate regions to serve users in those different areas. That's different from failing over. Failing over from North America to Asia doesn't seem to be a good solution for normal use cases. Neither region will serve users on the opposite continent all that well.

That said, you can kind of do this using round-robin DNS. If you've got a server in California with address ip1 and another server in Singapore with address ip2, just advertise the address for mywebsite.mydomain to be both ip1 and ip2. Through testing I've found that all recent web browsers will randomly try one address and, if it can't be connected to, try the other one. It looks pretty seamless to the user. But you're still routing American clients to Singapore, and vice versa, at random.